# How can we use protractor beforeAll and afterAll hooks for opening and closing a browser in each describe block

Tags: protractor

I have used the following but I get This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used. Can someone help with this.

**Sample.js file which has the following code:**

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
    beforeAll(function(){
         browser.get('https://xxxx/');
         console.log('calling before all');
     });

     afterAll(function(done){
         console.log('calling after all');
         browser.quit();
         process.nextTick(done);
     });
```

**Another file which also has the same code:**

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
        beforeAll(function(){
             browser.get('https://xxxx/');
             console.log('calling before all');
         });

         afterAll(function(done){
             console.log('calling after all');
             browser.quit();
             process.nextTick(done);
         });
```

Now I want to use beforeAll and AfterAll functions through which browser should open and close in each js file execution. When I follow this approach I get the error as This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

Comment: use `browser.close()`.

Comment: I used the same as well but issue remains the same. I want to open and close browser for every describe block.

Comment: You could try: `beforeAll(async function() { await browser.get('h.ttp...'); })`. Maybe protractor doesn't know that you are executing asynchronus functions within `beforeAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking because you only posted one `describe` but in the comments I see you said you want the browser to open before every `describe`. Assuming you have nested `describe` blocks you can just use `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` to do this.

```
describe('some test', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    //some setup code
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get('https://xxxx/');
  }

  afterEach(() => {
    browser.restart();
  }

  afterAll(() => {
    //some tear down code
  }

  describe('something', () => {
    it('should test something', () => {
      //test code
    }
  }

  describe('another thing', () => {
    it('should test another thing', () => {
      //test code
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above the order of execution would be:

```
describe
beforeAll
beforeEach (open browser)
describe - something
it - should test something
afterEach (close browser)
beforeEach (open browser)
describe - another thing
it - should test another thing
afterEach (close browser)
afterAll
```

There is also a protractor config option [restartBrowserBetweenTests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7f968e022a7f7ebcda8955651f2907c1a25ecc22/lib/config.ts#L501) that restarts the browser before each test but I don't think this is what you are asking for.

Comment: I have edited the original question. Please let me know if its clear

Comment: OK, try changing your `browser.quit()` to `browser.restart()` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need: 
beforeEach and
afterEach

They will execute before each "it" block within "describe".